# how to make a jquery independent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a jquery to validate my drop down. if 'yes' on radio box i can select from dropdown. if 'no' on radio box dropdown is greyed out.

If a both radio boxes are 'yes' and value in both dropdowns are 'please select'  and submit button is clicked, a validation error occurs and DOES NOT redirect to index.html.

If one radio box is at 'yes' & dropdown 'please select' and the other at 'no' with value 'red' from dropdown and submit button is clicked a validation error occors and redirect to index.html. Obviously this defeats the purpose of a validation.

I hope someone can help as its driving me mad.!

I have narrowed it down to this being the probem:

```
});      
       $("input:submit").click(function(){         
           var retVal = false;
           $.each([1, 2], function(i, val){
              retVal = (validate(val) || retVal);
           });
            return retVal;   
       });
```

Comment: in your code retVal is true if at least one validation succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `validate()` function (which you don't show) which validates the specified item and returns `true` if OK or `false` if invalid. On submit you want to call `validate()` for several items, and if *any* of them return `false` return `false` to the submit (conversely, return `true` only if *all* the validations are `true`.

The way your existing code sets `retVal`, once it becomes `true` it will *stay* `true` because any boolean result from `validate()` ORed with `true` will be `true`. Try this instead:

```
       $("input:submit").click(function(){         
           var retVal = true;
           $.each([1, 2], function(i, val){
              retVal = validate(val) && retVal;
           });
            return retVal;   
       });
```

This starts with a default return of `true`, and then changes it to `false` if `validate(val)` returns `false`. Using `&&` instead of `||` then means that once `retVal` is `false` it will stay `false`. In my opinion it would be clearer to just get rid of the `&&` altogether and say:

```
if (!validate(val)) retVal = false;
```

Comment: yes thats what I want to do. I put your code in, the dropdowns do not go grey if no is selected and no validation message occurs if at 'yes' and 'please select'.